# ambiguity error in function overloading

Tags: c++, overloading

```
class overload                         
{                                      
  void func(int x)
   {
     cout<<"pass by value\n";
   }
  public:void func(int &x)
    {
      cout<<"pass by reference\n";  
    }
};
main()
   {
      overload b1; 
      b1.func(10);
   }
```

i have made one function private and the other function with same name public.now in main only one function is visible,then why does the compiler gives ambiguity error when i am trying to access this function??

Comment: Because that's not allowed :)

Answer (score 2):

Overload resolution is performed before checking the access of a function. It's irrelevent that one is `private` - the overload resolution is still ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Overload resolution is done before access control. The compiler finds all functions with the name `func()` and tries to resolve to the most viable overload. Visibility isn't taken into account at that stage.